# Python 3 calling external DLL with custom data type

Tags: python, dll, types, ctypes

I'm trying to call an external DLL with the following header definition in C.

```
typedef long            EPC_INT32;
typedef void*           EPC_ADDR32;
typedef struct {EPC_CHAR a [16];} EPC_Str16;

typedef struct
{
   EPC_INT32 UseUSB;
   EPC_INT32 BoardNumber;
   EPC_INT32 FIFOSamples;
   EPC_INT32 MaxProbes;
   EPC_Str16 DeviceNumber;
   EPC_Str16 SerialNumber;
   EPC_INT32 ExternalScaling;
   EPC_ADDR32 DacScaling;
   EPC_ADDR32 AdcScaling;
} LIH_OptionsType;

typedef LIH_OptionsType* LIH_OptionsPtr;

EPC_INT32 EPC_Calling LIH_InitializeInterface(
            EPC_Str256Ptr ErrorMessage,
            EPC_INT32 Amplifier, 
            EPC_INT32 ADBoard,
            LIH_OptionsPtr OptionsPtr,
            EPC_INT32 OptionsSize ) EPC_Import;
```

Python code:

```
import ctypes
import sys

class LIH_Options(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("UseUSB",          ctypes.c_int32) ,
                ("BoardNumber",     ctypes.c_int32),
                ("FIFOSamples",     ctypes.c_int32),
                ("MaxProbes",       ctypes.c_int32),
                ("DeviceNumber",    ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ("SerialNumber",    ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ("ExternalScaling", ctypes.c_int32),
                ("DataScaling",     ctypes.c_void_p),
                ("AdcScaling",      ctypes.c_void_p)]

OptionsSize = sys.getsizeof(LIH_Options)

my_LIH_Options = LIH_Options(0,0,1024,0,'','',0, 0,0)  #create an instance

EPC = ctypes.WinDLL('EpcDLL.dll')


EPC.LIH_InitializeInterface.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,
                                        ctypes.c_int32, ctypes.c_int32,
                                        ctypes.POINTER(LIH_Options),
                                        ctypes.c_int32]

szErrMssg  = ctypes.create_string_buffer(256)

status = EPC.LIH_InitializeInterface(szErrMssg, 0, 3, my_LIH_Options, OptionsSize)
```

This returns a Tracback error:
status = EPC.LIH_InitializeInterface(szErrMssg, 0, int(LIH.Board), my_LIH_Options, OptionsSize)
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0xFFFFFFFF

If the call is replaced by

```
status = EPC.LIH_InitializeInterface(szErrMssg, 0, 3, None, OptionsSize)
```

it works, with the default values for LIH_Options.  So the problem is in passing the data type LIH_Options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array type and size of structure were incorrect.  This should work but untested as I don't have your DLL.  `None` is typically used for NULL pointers but 0 should work too.  Use byte strings (`b''`) for a `char` array.

```
import ctypes

# define the types for easier match to original C structure.
EPC_INT32 = ctypes.c_int32;
EPC_ADDR32 = ctypes.c_void_p; # Only 32-bit on a 32-bit OS.
EPC_CHAR = ctypes.c_char;     # Assumption...not defined in question
EPC_Str16 = EPC_CHAR * 16;    # Correct type of char[16] array

class LIH_Options(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("UseUSB",          EPC_INT32),
                ("BoardNumber",     EPC_INT32),
                ("FIFOSamples",     EPC_INT32),
                ("MaxProbes",       EPC_INT32),
                ("DeviceNumber",    EPC_Str16),
                ("SerialNumber",    EPC_Str16),
                ("ExternalScaling", EPC_INT32),
                ("DataScaling",     EPC_ADDR32),
                ("AdcScaling",      EPC_ADDR32)]

OptionsSize = ctypes.sizeof(LIH_Options)  # sys.getsizeof returns size of Python object, not C

my_LIH_Options = LIH_Options(0,0,1024,0,b'',b'',0,None,None)  #create an instance
EPC = ctypes.WinDLL('EpcDLL.dll')
EPC.LIH_InitializeInterface.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,
                                        EPC_INT32, EPC_INT32,
                                        ctypes.POINTER(LIH_Options),
                                        EPC_INT32]
szErrMssg  = ctypes.create_string_buffer(256)
status = EPC.LIH_InitializeInterface(szErrMssg, 0, 3, my_LIH_Options, OptionsSize)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions.  The suggested changes caused a different result, but now LIH_InitializeInterface() now hangs.  Moreover, I think I corrupted the BIOS because the interface no longer works with other software.  I think one problem is that LIH_Options requires pointers to the string variables DeviceNumber and SerialNumber, not the 16 char string itself.  In a working version (in FreeBasic), the sizeof(LIH_Options) is 64 bytes, not the 536 bytes returned in Python.  Perhaps this size is due to using class / _fields_

Comment: @SteveCannon Did you switch to `ctypes.sizeof`? `sys.getsizeof` is incorrect. I get 60 bytes for 32-bit Python, and 72 bytes for 64-bit Python.  And your C definition shows `EPC_Str16` is a `char[16]` array....not a pointer.  For what you provided the above is correct.

Comment: @MikeTolonen. You are correct.  I changed to ctypes.sizeof and it appears to be working (just need to get the hardware BIOS refreshed.  Thanks.